# How do I return just an individual string in bash?

Tags: regex, bash

I have a text file with multiple lines, but I know that on one line there's the following

`name="some_string" value="some_string"`

I know I can get down to the *line* by just `cat file.txt|grep "value=\".*\""` but I can't figure out just to return what's inside the parenthesis. I think grep can only get it down to the line

Comment: This smells a lot like you're searching through an XML file. If that's true, then the better solution is to use an XPath processor with a query like `//*[@name='hello']/@value`. That way it works even if the file is written with the name and the value on different lines, or with no whitespace at all, or with multiple name/value pairs on a single line, or in a different case that is valid XML but would provide an incorrect result with XML-unaware tools.

Comment: It is technically xml but it's outputted to the console as a result of running a command so I'm guaranteed it's going to be on that line, everytime. I suppose I could redirect the output to a file and then use the XPath processor you're talking about...does it require installation? I need this bash script to work on a regular user desktop, without asking them to install anything

Comment: if you want to work out-of-the-box on modern systems, the best way to get an XML processor is to lean on what Python has built-in; the best tool for running XPath from bash is (IMHO) XMLStarlet, but it doesn't tend to be installed out-of-the-box on modern distros. There's also a `--xpath` argument to xmllint, but older versions don't have it.

Comment: ...of course, not all systems have GNU grep either.

Comment: I see, unfortunately any installation is probably going discouraged, but I'll keep that in the back of my mind for future parsing, thanks!
edit: I think I can at least make the assumption that they will be running on Linux so I don't think grep should be an issue. If it was up to me I would make it as robust as possible but unfortunately I'm working on someone else's project

Comment: I've extended my version of the answer to have some answers which will work with only POSIX tools -- so not only no xmllint or xmlstarlet, but also POSIX grep only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using GNU `grep` for `-P` (PCRE) option and `-o` option to print only matched part.

```
grep -oP '(?<=value=")[^"]+' file
```

Comment: would you perhaps explain what the `?<=` means? I'm not familiar with that syntax. I know that `?` means "0 or 1" but I've never encountered the `<=` is that specific to perl?

Comment: @sreya `?<=` is a negative look behind assertion. We are trying to capture everything where the behind text is `value="` and up to the first `"`. Here is a good starter [tutorial](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Answer (score 1):

If your regex contains grouping operators, you can use `=~` and `BASH_REMATCH`:

```
regex='value="([^"]+)"'
[[ $string =~ $regex ]] && result=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

This works on systems (like MacOS) without GNU grep.

---

Another approach, which similarly works on systems with only POSIX grep, is to filter grep's output in native bash with parameter expansions:

```
while read -r; do
  value=${REPLY#*'value="'}
  value=${value%'"'*}
  echo "$value"
done < <(grep -e 'name="foo"' file)
```